# How to generate an $n \times n$ rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

It is well known that the $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix is given by,
$$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
and that there are  $3 \times 3$ rotation matrices to describe rotation in 3-dimensions,

$$R_{x}(\theta)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
$$R_{y}(\theta)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
$$R_{z}(\theta)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]$$
That is, there are three elements of the rotation group $SO(3)$, and there is one element of $SO(2)$. In general, I found that for $\phi$ elements of $SO(d)$, where $d$ is the dimension that $$\phi = \frac{d(d-1)}{2}$$
Yet, how is it that the explicit representation of say $R_{i}(\theta)$ is derived, where $i$ is some arbitrary element of $SO(d)$. Are these things all manually computed or is there a general formula/method for determining what they are? The reason I am asking is that I have a functional in configuration space $T$ that depends on a parameter $R_{j}^{i}$ that is summing over dimensions $i,j$. $R_{j}^{i} \in SO(d)$ is representing an $i \times j$ rotation matrix (note $d=i=j$) and I am having trouble explicitly constructing an $n$-dimensional example since I don't know how to represent an $n \times n$ rotation matrix. Any references to papers, or original responses are welcome.

Comment: Exponentiate a skew-symmetric matrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

Comment: The generalization of $R_x(\theta)$, $R_y(\theta)$, and $R_z(\theta)$ to $n$ dimensions are the [Givens rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

Comment: @RahulNarain: Could you give an explanation so I can accept it as an answer? The wikipedia page is blocked because of the SOPA act awareness thing.